# I cannot create folders or files in Powershell. When I type cd foldername I get an error

Tags: python, powershell

How do I create a folder and a file in Powershell on Windows? I am working through the first bit of `Learning Python 3 the Hard Way` and I am a complete beginner. I can type `mkdir directory1` into powershell and make a directory but when I put `cd folder1` I get an error.

I have tried checking whether I installed Python correctly and looked at others' examples.

```
PS C:\Users\bkann> mkdir directory1

    Directory: C:\Users\bkann


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                
d-----        7/28/2019   4:47 AM                directory3  

PS C:\Users\bkann> cd folder1
cd : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\bkann\folder3' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd folder3
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\bkann\folder3:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand


PS C:\Users\bkann>
```

Comment: cd is an alias for set-location, which allows your current directory to be changed to another directory. You can’t change into a directory that does not exist or one which you lack the proper permissions

Comment: you don't have `folder1` but `directory1` so use `cd directory1`. Or use `ls` or `dir` to check what names you have.

Comment: you created `directory1`, later you use `cd folder1` but error show `folder3` . Decide which name you use.

Comment: i cannot find any way to use `mkdir` with one dir name ... and get the display that you show [a _different dir  name_]. have you tried doing this in a different directory?

Answer (score -1):

New-Item -Path 'C:\Users\bkann\file.txt' -ItemType File -Force

Comment: The question contains mistyped path. Why would using `New-Item`'s _file creation_ help with _incorrect path_?